# MPLAB Harmony Configurator not working

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, mplab, mplab-harmony

After installing MPLAB Harmony Configurator from the available plugins in MPLAB (v5.05)

[image]

i tried to create a new project but it seems that harmony location is not valid?
I doesn't seem to have anything on PC related to it.
[image]

Comment: Just at a guess, you need to update your MPLAB installation.  Fair warning, though, even when you get Harmony properly installed, it won't really work.

Comment: It seems to work if i install the version 3 of harmony. strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non v1-2 Harmony you need to download and install the framework yourself

see download installer links on https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-harmony/mplab-harmony-1.0

then after installing , link the project harmony path to the install path